# Should spam bait questions be protected?

Tags: discussion, spam, protected-questions, spam-detection

Questions on "What website should I read to learn language X?" tend to attract spammers, such as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607923/user607923) who only answers such questions.

Rather than flagging such spammers, should the spam-bait questions be protected instead?

Comment: I speculated about another possibility [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75761/are-there-specific-topics-on-stack-overflow-that-attract-more-spammers-than-other), and that's to leave the spam-prone questions open as honeypots to more easily identify spammers.  I don't know how good of a suggestion it is, but I was able to track down a number of spammers just by looking at a couple of targeted questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually wait until a question has at least three spam answers before I protect it.  Protecting (unfortunately) prevents legitimate answers from new users as well as spammers.  If I can identify a spammer, I'd rather deal with them more directly.  If they keep coming back to the same questions after repeated cleansings, then I'll break down and protect the questions, cutting off the blood supply they feed upon.

Comment: this is going to get "complicated" ... Jeff just had me add "protect questions" as a 15k priv

Comment: @waffles: Well, that explains why I got the notification earlier.